# "ОБЕЗЫНТЕРНЕТЧЕН" (Интернет) - корневое Т сохраняется?

Tags: окказионализмы

> Я конкретно подсела к кому-то на Интернет. После серьёзной грозы.
>   Опять долбануло у нас электричество. Кондиционер – выжил. Роутер –
>   снова пал.
>
> Нам ещё очень повезло, что кто-то свой Интернет не запаролил.
>   Здесь на улицу не выйдешь и в кафе не засядешь. По сравнению с
>   Москвой, да что там, с деревней в Сербии – в Италии Интернета нет
>   (НИЗЗЯ ТАК. НУ СКАЖИ: ИТАЛИЯ ОБЕЗЫНТЕРНЕТЧЕНА, О_о). Так что,
>   пользуясь случаем, посылаю хвалу – спасибо тебе, о хозяин быстрого
>   потока!

В скобочках - это я резвлюсь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот нашлись *интернето-просторные* примеры.

1. Крохотный городок Сибай — весь **обынтернечен.**
2. ...я в Крыму и здесь очень нерегулярно **обынтернечен**.
3. В выходные, будучи почти добровольно **обезынтернечен**, посмотрел три художественных фильма из списка “когда-нибудь надо посмотреть”...

Думаю, что аналогия прослеживается: цве**т** — обесцве**т**ить — обесцве**ч**ен; трафаре**т** — трафаре**т**ить — трафаре**ч**ен; секре**т** — рассекре**т**ить — рассекре**ч**ен.

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что *интернетопросторный* слитно... )))

Comment: Обыграла словечко сама: на просторах интернета — интернет просторный. Сложилось для обозначения — откуда ж я повыцарапывала примеры. Честное слово, об орфографии не задумывалась. Можно и так: _интернетско-просторный_, _интернетовско-просторный_, _по-интернетски просторный_...

Answer (score 4):

Едва ли стоит ассоциировать такую полезность как Интернет с редкостно низменным (ветчина) или высоким (Тютчев), где **т** берётся не **от** неизменяемой приставки к **от**чётности. Навороты - и те всего лишь "наворо**ч**ены". Интернет - обезынтерне**чен**, биле**т** - о(без)биле**чен**, отве**т** - отве**чен**.

**P.S.** Простое "**лишён интернета**" содержит меньше букв и звучит явно лучше (не напоминает слов вроде "*присобачен*"). Если это не о действии, а о состоянии в прошлом (без слова "был" не обойтись), то ещё короче "(был) **без интернета**".

Answer (score 2):

1) В Сети  пишут ***обынтернеченный (иногда обинтернеченный)***, например: *Противопоставлять «обынтернеченный» электорат «необынтернеченному» более чем опасно.* Слова пока нет в словаре, соответственно, правильный выбор Ы/И  проверить негде.

**Примечание**. По правилам буква И после приставки на твердую согласную пишется **в трех случаях:** (1) *дезинформация, контригра* (после иноязычных приставок), (2) *мединститут* (сложносокращенное слово), (3) *межинститутский, сверхизысканный* (после Ж и Х).

2) В словообразовательном словаре Ефремовой указано наличие обязательного **чередование Т/Ч** перед суффиксом ЕНН, например: ***провертеть — проверченный.***

Поэтому ***обезынтернетить — обезынтернеченный***. Наличие сочетания ТЧ в причастии исключается.

3) Сравнить со словами, где есть **сочетание ТЧ**: немец — немет/чин/а, совет/ск/ий — антисоветчина. Здесь  суффикс ЧИН/ЩИН (ЧИН после Д и Т).

Comment: *выбор Ы/И — неустоявшийся* — а разве известен хотя бы один случай, когда устоялся выбор **и** в первой букве корня после приставки "об" (или той же "без") с последующим попаданием в словари? Всегда думал, что это правило не может иметь исключений.

Comment: Ответ исправлен. К сожалению, в наши правилах не объясняется, почему в некоторых случаях пишется И в корне, а не Ы, в то время как в других морфемах запись делается по слуху (Ы/И, ИН/ЫН). А так как исключения встречаются для иноязычных приставок, выбор И распространяют на иноязычный корень. Собственного говоря, никто не объясняет, почему этого делать нельзя.

Answer (score -1):

А ответ - обезинтернетен. 
Обезнтер**нечен** и обезинтер**нетен**. Одно из них, видимо, говорит об отключении (о самом действии отключения, типа: "он отключен" (имеется в виду отключён нами)), а второе - о положении, об обстоятельстве в котором кто-то находится.

Comment: Правило написания **И/Ы** после приставок на согласный: инициативный — **безынициативный**; искусный — **безыскусный**. https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/napisanie-i-yi-posle-pristavok-primeryi.html

Comment: Ага, во-первых, правила для каких слов: русских или иностранных? Во-вторых, правила для "без", а не для "обез".

Comment: Слово окказиональное, новое, русское. И приставки в нем русские: О + БЕЗ (**без** — последняя перед корнем, начинающимся с И), поэтому правило изменения И на Ы, считаю, обязательно должно "работать".

Comment: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/eng_rus/19227/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x

Comment: @Нижегородец Я "сильно много" доверяю **Большому толковому словарю**: безЫнерционный. http://www.вокабула.рф/словари/бтс/безынерционный И **словарю Ефремовой**: безЫнерционный. https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-4083.htm

Comment: Ничего страшного, наберите "бези" по ссылке http://www.вокабула.рф

Comment: @Нижегородец Обезинтернетен  - неверная форма для причастия,  чередование Т/Ч согласно словообразовательному словарю Ефремовой является обязательным. Это краткое прилагательное:.безинтернетный - безинтернетен.

Comment: Я не понял ваш ответ. Причём тут "неверная форма причастия?

Comment: 1) Глагол и причастие: обезинтернетить - обезинтернечен. 2) Прилагательное полное и краткое: безинтернетный  - безинтернетен.